# Nexus One - Android 2.1 release, WHERE is the SDK for 2.1?

Tags: android

The Nexus android phone went on sale today with 2.1 Os on them.  My friend 
just ordered two with overnight shipping. I assume that means it will be in his hands tomorrow or the next day.

How is it even remotely acceptable that people will have 2.1 in their 
hands before developers even get to touch the SDK?  I already have 
users using the Nexis-Droid 2.1 rom saying that my highly used widget 
doesn't work.  How am I supposed to test this out in advance without 
hacking our phone all up?

All this does is frustrate users when apps don't work and further 
degrades the market with 1 stars because developers don't have a 
chance to update their code.

Thanks google....

Comment: Are you targeting 2.0.1?

Comment: I am only targeting a min sdk of 3 (OS 1.5). I do not believe that there is a "max sdk" entrie that I can put in the manifest file to block 2.1 users until I have the chance to update the app.

Comment: Tell them it's tough. They're using a hacked, not production release of 2.1 and the kind of people that use advanced release ROMs know that not everything will run smoothely.

Comment: I can't comment to them since it's a comment on the market. I tried to match the name up with the people that have purchased it and couldn't on this one.

Comment: If you want me to have a look on a real Nexus One (which I'm using to type this comment) just ping the details to skeet@pobox.com.

Comment: You can add a `<uses-sdk />` tag in your manifest with the attribute `android:maxSdkVersion="6"` to restrict your application to devices running 2.0.1 or below.

Comment: The SDK has been released: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/01/android-21-sdk.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can expect the SDK in a few days.  Google said it would be "open-sourced" in the next couple of days.  It does suck that we don't have it yet.  If I remember correctly, we received 2.0 about a week before the DROID was released, and we got 2.0.1 about the same time frame before it was pushed down to the DROID.
2. People using an OS that isn't available should not be complaining about apps not working.  It's their choice to be an adopter of an OS that isn't even released yet.  They can deal with the consequences. (which has nothing to do with you)

The part I hate about the market is our inability to respond to ratings.  I have more than 2500 ratings for my app, yet I constantly get 1-stars because the users are morons and can't read.  Yet I only have 325 characters for my app desciption.  I have started writing my own comments and updating it to respond to ratings.

Comment: I agree with your point #2 totally but that doesn't stop them from commenting on my App in the market.

2.0.1 wasn't a major OS release so I didn't have to update anything to maintain support, I did have to on 2.0 though. I also expect to have to with 2.1. My only option at this point is to stick the hacked 2.1 on my rooted Droid to see what the errors are and hope that they are the same as the real OS.

Comment: I know what you mean.  I get comments all the time about my app not working on the Nexus One, when the application listing specifically states it only works on the Droid/Milestone.  It's not by choice that I make it work only on those devices, so it's out of my control as to whether it works on other devices.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't developed anything yet for Android but have looked into the SDK a bit.

I saw is possible to specify a maxSdkVersion in the manifest. 
I'd say developers should put there the max version of the SDK that they've been able to test.

So if no SDK 2.1 is available yet and you put 2.0 or 2.0.1 there, it will prevent Nexus One users to download your application (I'm guessing here it works that way).

It would be in the interest of Google to release the SDK if Nexus One users cannot download and install any application at all. The users will be blaming Google then instead of you.

Edit: Oops, somebody commented it before.

Answer (score 0):

[Android 2.1, Release 1 SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.1.html)

The SDK has been released; this is the first time that an Android SDK has followed the release of a device running that version.