# HTC Nexus emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, emulation

Is there an emulator for the [Nexus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_One) ?  i want to test some of my android apps on it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2008756/nexus-one-android-2-1-release-where-is-the-sdk-for-2-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The android 2.1 SDK has just been released:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.1.html

The emulator doesn't contain the Nexus One skin but it emulates all of the APIs so it should be good for testing.